# Google Sheets - Lookup with Mulitple Criteria

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, lookup

Trying to work out formula to look up record from a 2nd Tab based on 3 cell values in current Tab.

Shared example of my sheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RgOn6KoFpcwc_puxdvYO5NK12RwlRMUBfUdLntQSiC4/edit?usp=sharing

Any help or pointers appreciated.  Have been googling for days but can not find specific answer to this situation.  Combined with me being some-what a novice isn't helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the cell values in the Summary sheet, and also the corresponding values in the Parts sheet, and do an index/match (could also use VLOOKUP with an array expression like {B:B&C:C&D:D,A:A} if you wanted to).

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(index(Parts!$A:$A,match($A3&C$2&B$1&C$1,Parts!$B:$B&Parts!$C:$C&Parts!$D:$D,0))))
```

entered into C3 and pulled across and down.

Note that I have included B1 & C1 in the concatenation. This is because of the merged cells - the right-hand cell in each merged pair in the Section cells will always be empty, so this guarantees that a non-empty string will be used.

[image]

In principle you could develop a single array formula to fill all the cells, but that would probably be overkill.

Here is the Vlookup version for comparison

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup($A3&C$2&B$1&C$1,{Parts!$B:$B&Parts!$C:$C&Parts!$D:$D,Parts!$A:$A},2,false)))
```

For the record, a single array formula wouldn't be any longer:

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup(A3:A5&B2:I2&A1:H1&B1:I1,{Parts!B:B&Parts!C:C&Parts!D:D,Parts!A:A},2,false)))
```